# Using an iterator to print out every member of a set

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I'm trying to use an iterator to print out every member of a set. As far as I can tell from other stackoverflow answers, I have the correct formatting. When I run this code, it correctly outputs that the size of myset is 3, but it only outputs ii once. If I uncomment the line with *iter, Visual Studio throws a runtime exception saying that that "map/set iterator is not dereferencable. Any idea why?

```
int main()
{
set<int> myset;
myset.insert(5);
myset.insert(6);
myset.insert(7);
set<int>::iterator iter;
cout<<myset.size()<<endl;
int ii=0;
for(iter=myset.begin(); iter!=myset.end();++iter);{
    //cout<<(*iter)<<endl;
    ii+=1;
    cout<<ii<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have an extra `;` in this line:

```
for(iter=myset.begin(); iter!=myset.end();++iter);{
```

This means that the loop's body is actually empty, and the following lines are executed once only.

So change that line to this:

```
for(iter=myset.begin(); iter!=myset.end();++iter) {
```