# How does one output an iterator in C++?

Tags: c++

I think this question has been asked earlier, but I couldn't find any answer.
I'm interested in how one can output an iterator(i.e. the value of the iterator).
I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: C++ iterators normally follow the semantics of pointers, so the dereference operator `operator*` should return a reference to the object pointed to by the iterator. The stream inserter should be overloaded for this kind of object if you wish to get output.

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of the iterator"? An iterator doesn't have a public value representation; if you mean the value it refers to, then dereference it, `*it`.

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742491/using-an-iterator-to-print-out-every-member-of-a-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a

```
std::vector<int> values;
```

And you have an iterator from a loop

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
for (it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << *it; // dereference the iterator
}
```